# Where does the Windows 10 game bar store ongoing background recordings, on disk or in memory?

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, xbox-game-dvr

When you enable the background recording feature of the Windows 10 "game bar", so that you can record a (by default) 30-second clip on demand, where is the ongoing recording stored? "In memory" would be believable, as it would only take a few hundred megabytes as a rough estimate, but if it's "on disk", then those of us with SSDs might want to redirect it from its default location, with a symlink if necessary. If it is on disk, then where?

To be clear, I'm referring to the temporary data that is in use by the background recording feature before you save a clip. The location in which finalized clips are saved is easily discoverable.

If the version matters, I'm specifically interested in Windows 10 1909, but a more general answer could be useful.

Comment: Your concerns about the SSD are at least one full decade outdated. If this is the only reason for your question I suggest you move on with your life.

Comment: The location where these videos are stored are user configurable.  What research have you done?  The location is configured through the Settings UWP application.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not asking about the finished recordings that you have told it to save permanently. I'm talking about the in-progress background recording. Or is that stored in the same location (user\Videos\Captures, as I recall)? For research, I did plenty of searching via Google but found no answers.

Comment: A temporary file is not store in **../Videos/Captures**

Comment: Indeed. I'm glad we have that determined. The main question still remains, being surprisingly difficult to answer. Anyone who thinks it's a poor one is welcome to comment about why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `iTsFx`, an `Independent Advisor` on [the Microsoft Community Answers forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/xba_frsocial-xbo_sharestream/where-is-temporary-footage-from-game-bar-captures/27606a31-3a58-4cb7-82c1-6755512e75fb),

> The temporary data for background recordings in the Windows Game Bar is stored in the RAM of your computer and is not saved to disk. It is stored as a buffer in the memory, and the video is not saved to disk until you explicitly choose to save it by pressing Win + Alt + G and selecting "Save".

> Once you choose to save the recording, it is saved to a folder of your choice on your local disk. By default, the saved recordings are stored in the "Videos" folder in your "Documents" directory. You can change the default save location for the recordings by going to the Windows Game Bar settings and modifying the "Recorded videos" option.

I cannot independently verify that at this time, and this person does not appear to be a developer, but it is the most authoritative answer I have yet found.