# Does Windows 11 Xbox Game Bar instant replay feature hurt disk drive?

Tags: windows, ssd, gaming

I was wondering if this feature constantly writes to my NVMe SSD degrading it's performance. I thought features like this store replays somewhere in RAM or VRAM, but quick googling showed that similar feature (NVIDIA Shadowplay) actually constantly writes to disk. Does game bar handles this feature differently?

Comment: Modern SSDs are pretty robust, so you don't have to worry.

Comment: @harrymc I disagree. "High quality" Game Bar videos occupy 1 GiB per 3 minutes. A 250 GiB Samsung 980 Pro has only 150 TBW for endurance. That would be exhausted in as little as 850 hours of gameplay (150 × 1024 ÷ 3 ÷ 60). For comparison, I played Monster Hunter World for 1,800 hours over the course of a couple of years. Even for the 2 TiB version with 8 times that endurance, to unnecessarily burn through 25% or more of the drive's lifespan in a couple of years is not "don't worry" territory, in my opinion.

Comment: @Corrodias: RAM usage has no relation to disk usage, unless the computer is too small for the game, and in this case playing would be impossibly slow.

Comment: @harrymc the whole point of this question is whether the recording buffer is on disk or in RAM: if it's constantly recording *to disk* during gameplay then on an SSD that is nontrivial wear.  Fortunately the answer seems to indicate "in RAM"

Comment: @MarkSowul: The point is that a game that worked directly with the disk all the time will have such an atrocious performance that it will never be released. It can't exist.

Comment: This is talking about a Windows feature that is basically like a dashcam for video games.  It is constantly recording the game in the background, and when you tell it to do so, it will dump the last 5 minutes to disk.  The question is whether it is behaving like an actual dashcam, which obviously writes to its disk in the background the whole time and thus wears it out.  It has nothing to do with a video game's usage of RAM

Answer (score 2):

So I just tested this in Elden Ring and it saves a running buffer of the video into RAM.  When I put it up to 5 minutes at high capture settings and 60 fps the RAM usage for GameDVR went up to over 3GB but still didn't write to disk until I pressed the capture button for background recording

[image: task manager stats]

[image: game capture settings]

Comment: I asked a similar question here. https://superuser.com/questions/1503221/where-does-the-windows-10-game-bar-store-ongoing-background-recordings-on-disk - The words of the `Independent Advisor` agree with this answer. I like the demonstration of memory usage and lack of disk usage, although with SSDs, it can be hard to prove that a disk is "almost idle".